# canvas.mpl_connect in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in test.py:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print('button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

when i run test.py in the command line by "python test.py", 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' gets printed as i click the plot

however, the results are not printed in jupyter notebook.

how to fix it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It will depend which backend you use in jupyter notebook.

- If you use the inline backend (i.e. `%matplotlib inline`), interactive features cannot work, because the plots are just png images.
- If you use the notebook backend (i.e. `%matplotlib notebook`) the interactive features do work, but the question would be where to print the result to. So in order to show the text one may add it to the figure as follows

  ```
  %matplotlib notebook
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))
  text=ax.text(0,0, "", va="bottom", ha="left")

  def onclick(event):
      tx = 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' % (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
      text.set_text(tx)

  cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
  ```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. Too bad the matplotlib notebook doesn't connect to the regular print() command.

Comment: And in the gui backends, the interactive features and printing both work, but the graph is in a separate window instead of in the notebook.

Comment: To anyone looking for an answer: using the magic commands `%matplotlib widget` or `%matplotlib ipympl` (requires ipympl package) allows for normal print commands.

Comment: When I run the code above I get, Javascript Error: IPython is not defined. The line that causes it is 'fig = plt.figure()'. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @stew I had the same issue with jupyter lab. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416229/11756613 this fixed it