# Javascript Error: IPython is not defined in JupyterLab

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have the latest/updated Anaconda package. Everytime I try to plot something using python 3.6.6 I get the following error in JupyterLab...

> Javascript Error: IPython is not defined

When I run the same code in Spyder using an ipython kernel, it works just fine. Have been looking all over online but cant seem to figure out what is going on. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Installing the [jupyter-matplotlib extension](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) is the path forward, as described inTomNorway's answer, which I think should become the accepted answer. For a quick workaround, do `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: For anyone working with jupyterlab 3, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68496287

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Jupyter Lab does support interactive matplotlib through the [jupyter-matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) extension. See [**TomNorway**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416229/14637).

**Alternatively**, you can configure matplotlib to use `inline` instead. `inline` is not as powerful as `interactive`, but it can save you.

To use `inline`, add this line before plot the graph:

```
    %matplotlib inline
```

[More Info](https://github.com/nteract/nteract/issues/1359)

Comment: Note that the quote and link are from a different project:`nteract`, not Jupyter Lab. And this is a workaround. It appears that the [jupyter-matplotlib extension](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib) is the path forward, as described in a separate answer, which I think should become the accepted answer
But thanks - it is indeed a quick, helpful fix!

Comment: This has not worked for me in jupyter, jupyter lab, and now jupyter hub

Comment: Not work jupyterlab.

Answer (score 134):

Jupyter Lab does support interactive matplotlib through the [jupyter-matplotlib extension](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib). The installation procedure is slightly more involved, but works fine. Since the ipympl Jupyter Lab version requires NodeJS, and NodeJS requires Windows 8.1, ipympl also has this requirement.

As before, it is important to invoke the iPython magic command before plotting:

## Usage:

`%matplotlib widget`

## Installation:

Note: If using this extension with Jupyter Lab, it's recommended to use a version >= 3. For more detailed instructions on installing an old extension than below, see the [instructions on ipympl github](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#use-in-jupyterlab).

### Using conda

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl

# If using JupyterLab 2
conda install nodejs
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter lab build

# Later, if updating a previous Lab install:
conda install ipympl
jupyter lab build
```

### Using pip

```bash
pip install ipympl

# If using JupyterLab 2
pip install nodejs-bin
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib
```

Comment: On my machine it prints `Error displaying widget` and doesn't show the graph. `jupyter labextension list` command prints:  
`@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v0.38.1  enabled  OK
jupyter-matplotlib v0.3.0  enabled  OK`

Comment: You may need to update to jupyter lab v 1.0, which has been released in the past few days. jupyter-matplotlib v0.3.1 was also just released today. Try installing those, running the above jupyter labextension commands, and report back.

Comment: Thank you, i've been using jupyterlab `v0.35`, now everything works great with `v1.0.2`

Comment: anyone else who gets the "npm dependencies failed to install" in ubuntu with jupyterlab 1.1.1 ?

Comment: There were issues once ipympl added support for jupyterlab 1.2. I suggest you either update jupyterlab or install the older ipympl version 3.3 (not sure if any later versions will work). `conda install ipympl=0.3.3` or `pip install ipympl==0.3.3`

Comment: And also enable that extension with `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`. And restart whole notebook/lab

Comment: Update from the newest ipyml version (https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl):
Starting from ipympl `0.5.6`, you do not need to manually install the JupyterLab extension, but you still need to install the JupyterLab widget manager.
`jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`

`# If you already installed the @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager extension, you will still need to rebuild JupyterLab after you installed ipympl`
`jupyter lab build`

Comment: It seems that nodejs is no longer needed to be installed manually.

Comment: Just a heads-up for users of JupyterLab 3.0.12 (to the least): all of a sudden, `%matplotlib widget` stopped working, with the above error. I had to manually uninstall (`jupyter labextension uninstall`, `conda uninstall`…) and then reinstall all the packages as per TomNorway’s answer.

Comment: Using current conda version (v4.10, 06/2021) with a python 3.9.5 environment, `conda install nodejs` installs nodejs v6.X but `jupyter labextension install [...]` requires nodejs >=v12.0. Workaround is to install nodejs with `conda install nodejs -c conda-forge --repodata-fn=repodata.json`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325068/cannot-install-latest-nodejs-using-conda-on-mac)

Answer (score 9):

Encountered similar issue when using backtrader.
This fixed it for me:

```
cerebro.plot(iplot = False)
```

Comment: This works finally. `%matplotlib inline; cerebro.plot(iplot = False)`

Answer (score 6):

1. Jupyterlab supports jpympl.
2. You must put `%matplotlib widget` in the very beginning of the jupyterlab.

You can change to `%matplotlib inline` in specific cell, and active `%matplotlib widget` again if needed.

Otherwise, no matter how many times you reinstall the package, you will still get the errors.

Answer (score 6):

I could solve the same problem by installing `ipympl`:

```
pip install ipympl
```

And then add `%matplotlib ipympl` before plot.

Answer (score 0):

After installing ipympl, then reinstalling jupyter-lab the way to get it to work was by importing like:

```
%matplotlib ipyml
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how your information differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67492351/8508004) already posted here by Keivan? Also [the current highest scoring one in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416229/8508004) also already inlcudes this information, especially if you read [the documentation where the basic Example](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example) says, "To activate the `ipympl` backend all you need to do is include the `%matplotlib ipympl` magic in the notebook. Alternatively you can use `%matplotlib widget` which will have the same effect.".

Answer (score -1):

I was getting Ipython not defined in jupyter notebook when I tried to display a html formated content in my jupyter notebook, I just imported the function and it worked

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML # my imports

annot = coco_dataset.display_image(21, use_url=False) #my function return a html page

HTML(annot) # used for displaying the page
```

Answer (score -1):

Install Anaconda and start notebook from anaconda navigator. It resolves my problem.(The solution above didn't work for me. )

Comment: This did not work for me and I always start from the Anaconda Navigator.  I just started getting this error as well in a Notebook I've been using for weeks.