# jupyter lab build fails because of node

Tags: python, node.js, anaconda, jupyter

I am using jupyter managed by anaconda. Trying to build extensions, I get the error:

```
 > jupyter lab build
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 1.2.6
[LabBuildApp] Building in /opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod:minimize)
[LabBuildApp] WARNING | 
"nbdime-jupyterlab@2.0.0" is not compatible with the current JupyterLab
Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab             Extension      Package
>=1.2.1 <1.3.0         >=2.0.0 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/apputils
>=3.2.0 <3.3.0         >=4.0.0 <5.0.0 @jupyterlab/coreutils
>=1.2.2 <1.3.0         >=2.0.0 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/notebook
>=1.2.1 <1.3.0         >=2.0.0 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/rendermime
>=4.2.0 <4.3.0         >=5.0.0 <6.0.0 @jupyterlab/services


An error occured.
RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install
See the log file for details:  /var/folders/s4/msbdmzl11k1frxr21fdngkbw0000gn/T/jupyterlab-debug-cl5xoyof.log
```

Inspecting the log file:

```
[LabBuildApp] > node /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.15.2
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning @jupyterlab/plotly-extension > plotly.js > regl-splom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
warning @jupyterlab/plotly-extension > plotly.js > point-cluster > bubleify > buble > os-homedir@2.0.0: This is not needed anymore. Use `require('os').homedir()` instead.
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error ws@7.2.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8.3.0". Got "6.13.1"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] npm dependencies failed to install
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 98, in start
    command=command, app_options=app_options)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 459, in build
    command=command, clean_staging=clean_staging)

[LabBuildApp]   File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py", line 660, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

The problem seems to be an outdated `node`. I have a current version of `node` on my system, but Anaconda seems to use its own older version. How could I upgrade this?

Comment: see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325068/cannot-install-latest-nodejs-using-conda-on-mac/62357038#62357038 - that seems to be a conda solver glitch that can be worked around by using the hack in the answer there or using mamba instead of conda

Answer (score 0):

I find debugging the `node` problem too demanding and went to "overwrite" the buggy conda environment.

```
    conda create -n NameOfEnv python
    # Specifying the Python version, for oTree installation
    conda activate NameOfEnv
    # Getting the necessary packages for the current virtual env;
    conda install -y -c conda-forge jupyterlab nodejs yarn
    conda install -y -c anaconda pandas
```