# Problem with elasticdump installation: async _loop Unexpected identifier error

Tags: elasticsearch, npm, installation, elastic-stack

Installing `elasticdump` throws a bunch of warnings like so

```
$ npm install -g elasticdump
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated s3signed@0.1.0: This module is no longer maintained. It is provided as is.
/Users/ebeisaac/.npm-packages/bin/elasticdump -> /Users/ebeisaac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/elasticdump
/Users/ebeisaac/.npm-packages/bin/multielasticdump -> /Users/ebeisaac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/bin/multielasticdump
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for elasticdump@6.56.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"6.13.1","npm":"6.14.9"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: elasticdump@6.56.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fast-csv@4.3.5: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"6.13.1","npm":"6.14.9"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fast-csv@4.3.5
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for p-queue@6.6.2: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"6.13.1","npm":"6.14.9"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: p-queue@6.6.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for p-timeout@3.2.0: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"6.13.1","npm":"6.14.9"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: p-timeout@3.2.0

+ elasticdump@6.56.0
updated 1 package in 15.284s
```

After which, the executable always throws the following error when it is called

```
$ elasticdump --version   
/Users/ebeisaac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/lib/processor.js:40
  async _loop (limit, offset, totalWrites) {
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ebeisaac/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/elasticdump.js:3:28)
```

I even tried installing `npm` exactly as how it is done in [this website](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689). The outcome is still the same.

How to resolve this issue and get `elasticdump` to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs:

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for p-timeout@3.2.0: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"6.13.1","npm":"6.14.9"})
```

You are using node.js version 6.x, but it does not support node v6. You need to upgrade to v8 or later.

You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump/issues/558) and [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump/issues/634) Github issues

There [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62325068/4565943) in `conda` that prevents it from installing the latest nodejs version in a Mac. In which case, the solution would be to **uninstall the `conda` version** [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63679906/4565943) and use an alternative like homebrew or a pkg from [the official site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

**Note: do not have both conda and homebrew versions installed in the same time**, otherwise even executing homebrew's `npm` would throw the same error shown in the question.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on how to upgrade npm to solve this issue? Right now, I'm using anaconda and I am not able to install the latest npm due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325068/cannot-install-latest-nodejs-using-conda-on-mac). Or should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Thank you, the solution is resolved. I just needed to uninstall the conda version and use the homebrew version instead.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac glad this worked for you :) Can you please accept the answer as well :)

Comment: Yes, but I had to take additional non-trivial steps for the resolution. Shall I add those steps to your answer and then accept it?

Comment: Sure @ÉbeIsaac :)