# Jupiter notebook is printing words before plotting my images (not correct order)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In my code, I have it so that first images are plotted and then the user is asked to choose an image.

But when I run the cell, the user is first asked to choose an image and then the images are plotted. Not sure why.

Code in this picture:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter will render the plot after everthing else if it is running in 'inline' mode. I can't reproduce what you have exactly but take the following example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0,10,10)
y = 5*x +2


plt.plot(x,y)
print('Text is here first even though the plot call comes last')
```

The output of this looks like:

[Plot example without inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSME9.png)

So the plot is rendered last. Instead if we add '%matplotlib notebook' to the start. The plot will be rendered interactively and before the text.  If you want to switch back just change it to '%matplotlib inline'. There are a number of other backend plotting options that are worth exploring.

Comment: I tried doing that but it still happens in the reverse order and I also get this error "Javascript error: IPython is not defined"

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922480/javascript-error-ipython-is-not-defined-in-jupyterlab