# Interact with graphs in jupyter lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, jupyter-lab, interaction

I´ve been trying to create interactive graphs in jupyter lab, I used:

```
%matplotlib widget
```

But then I got this message:

```
Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: widget. Using notebook instead.
```

and when I tried to plot a histogram, I got:

```
Javascript Error: IPython is not defined
```

So, what should I do? I just want to zoom on histrograms.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922480/javascript-error-ipython-is-not-defined-in-jupyterlab

Answer (score 0):

Use `%matplotlib notebook`. It will let you zoom in/out of your graphs.

Comment: I get :IPython is not defined

Comment: are you using jupyter lab ?