# Jupyter lab build fail after installing plotly extension

Tags: installation, pip, plotly, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

Plotly figures are not rendered/displayed in jupyterlab. I therefore tried to install the extension jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager jupyterlab-plotly. Afterwards I was asked to run the jupyter lab build and this failed. I have no idea where the problem is.

**Install info:**
I installed a venv with pyenv running python 3.8.5.

jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.4.0
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.25.0
ipykernel        : 6.0.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.12
nbconvert        : 6.1.0
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5

npm --version
7.11.2

node --version
v16.1.0

I am restricted to use WSL1 because of company requirements.

I’ll post below the command outputs for

- jupyter labextension list
- jupyter lab build
- cat /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-5vr2zquq.log
- jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager --minimize=False

Any advice would be appreciated. I have no idea how to fix this.
Thanks

```
❯ jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v3.0.16
/home/bebop/.local/share/jupyter/labextensions
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)

/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/neue_fische/ot/ot-sopra_steria/.venv/share/jupyter/labextensions
jupyterlab-plotly v5.1.0 enabled OK

Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
app dir: /mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/neue_fische/ot/ot-sopra_steria/.venv/share/jupyter/lab
plotlywidget v4.14.3 enabled OK

Build recommended, please run jupyter lab build:
plotlywidget needs to be included in build
```

```
❯ jupyter lab build
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 3.0.16
[LabBuildApp] Building in /mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
Build failed.
Troubleshooting: If the build failed due to an out-of-memory error, you
may be able to fix it by disabling the dev_build and/or minimize options.

If you are building via the jupyter lab build command, you can disable
these options like so:

jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False

You can also disable these options for all JupyterLab builds by adding these
lines to a Jupyter config file named jupyter_config.py:

c.LabBuildApp.minimize = False
c.LabBuildApp.dev_build = False

If you don’t already have a jupyter_config.py file, you can create one by
adding a blank file of that name to any of the Jupyter config directories.
The config directories can be listed by running:

jupyter --paths

Explanation:

    dev-build: This option controls whether a dev or a more streamlined
    production build is used. This option will default to False (i.e., the
    production build) for most users. However, if you have any labextensions
    installed from local files, this option will instead default to True.
    Explicitly setting dev-build to False will ensure that the production
    build is used in all circumstances.

    minimize: This option controls whether your JS bundle is minified
    during the Webpack build, which helps to improve JupyterLab’s overall
    performance. However, the minifier plugin used by Webpack is very memory
    intensive, so turning it off may help the build finish successfully in
    low-memory environments.

An error occured.
shutil.Error: [(’/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/templates’, ‘/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab/staging/templates’, “[Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab/staging/templates’”)]
See the log file for details: /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-5vr2zquq.log
```

```
❯ cat /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-5vr2zquq.log
[LabBuildApp] Building in /mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v16.1.0

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp] File “/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/debuglog.py”, line 47, in debug_logging
yield

[LabBuildApp] File “/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py”, line 166, in start
raise e

[LabBuildApp] File “/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py”, line 162, in start
build(name=self.name, version=self.version,

[LabBuildApp] File “/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py”, line 469, in build
return handler.build(name=name, version=version, static_url=static_url,

[LabBuildApp] File “/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py”, line 657, in build
self._populate_staging(

[LabBuildApp] File “/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/commands.py”, line 1180, in _populate_staging
shutil.copytree(pjoin(HERE, ‘staging’, ‘templates’), templates)

[LabBuildApp] File “/home/bebop/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/shutil.py”, line 554, in copytree
return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,

[LabBuildApp] File “/home/bebop/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/shutil.py”, line 510, in _copytree
raise Error(errors)

[LabBuildApp] shutil.Error: [(’/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/templates’, ‘/mnt/s/dokumente/Privatpath/.venv/share/jupyter/lab/staging/templates’, “[Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab/staging/templates’”)]

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

```
❯ jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager --minimize=False

Building jupyterlab assets (production, not minimized)
An error occured.
shutil.Error: [(’/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/templates’, ‘/mnt/s/dokumente/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab/staging/templates’, “[Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘/mnt/s/dokumente/Privat/path/.venv/share/jupyter/lab/staging/templates’”)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to install the extension from source. JupyterLab 3.0 introduced prebuilt extensions system that allows users to install extensions from pip (and conda) without the need for the build step making all the trouble of troubleshooting failed builds disappear. It seems that you used an old set of instructions for installing plotly, as plotly 5.0+ supports prebuilt extensions for JupyterLab. First uninstall the source extensions that you just installed (non of those are needed):

```
jupyter labextension uninstall @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager jupyterlab-plotly plotlywidget
```

Optional: verify list of extensions with:

```
jupyter labextension list
```

Then install a new plotly version with pip or conda:

```sh
pip install "plotly>=5" "ipywidgets>=7.6"
# or, if using conda:
# conda install -c conda "plotly>=5"
# conda install "ipywidgets>=7.6"
```

Both widget and renderer are included, so no need to install `plotlywidget` separately.

Check list of extensions again:

```
jupyter labextension list
```

You should now see lines with:

```
jupyterlab-plotly v5.1.0 enabled OK
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
```

(the version may be newer in the future of course).