# Save changes in a python script using command

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I open my Python scripts on JupyterLab and make some changes if required. And I need to save changes using written command in my script. Something that will immitate `CTRL+S` command and do update my local file with all the changes.

Does anybody know how to handle this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

There are some python modules to handle this situation for you(like [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) and [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) ).
but they are not built-in python and first of all you have to install them using  ***pip install*** command(you have to have admin privilege to install them).
but if you want to save your python script using a command in Jupyter, you can use the following command in a jupyter cell and press Enter:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.save_notebook()
```

It will automatically save your changes.

Comment: It gives an error: ```Javascript Error: IPython is not defined.``` 
Any ideas?

Comment: I just search this error and found this result for you:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922480/javascript-error-ipython-is-not-defined-in-jupyterlab) I hope it could solve your problem.

Comment: Probably this solutions is OK for ```%matplotlib widget```. Unfortuantely it does not help with ```%%javascript```. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyboard` module.

```
import keyboard # Do pip install keyboard if it shows ModuleNotFoundError
#Your code
keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + s') #Saves the code
```

Comment: There is and error:

```ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.```

Comment: I am using JupyterLab on corporate server and do not have root access.

Comment: @ZaurHuseynov `sudo pip3 install keyboard` try this when installing the module

Comment: I cannot initiate this command because I do not have admin privileges.

Comment: @ZaurHuseynov In that case it's not possible to run the keyboard module since you are on a server.  There might be a way to do it in Javascript.

Comment: You are right. I would be so happy if you can help me to find the solution.