# Javascript Error: IPython is not defined in JupyterLab 3.2 in backtrader

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I tried every solution in this post:

[Javascript Error: IPython is not defined in JupyterLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922480/javascript-error-ipython-is-not-defined-in-jupyterlab)

yet, receive the same error in jupyterLab 3.3.2 (but it properly worked in VScode). Any would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, I have uninstalled juypter and notebooks:

```
    pip install pip-autoremove
    pip-autoremove jupyter -y

    python -m pip uninstall -y jupyter jupyter_core jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyterlab_pygments notebook qtconsole nbconvert nbformat jupyterlab-widgets nbclient jupyter-server-mathjax jupyterlab-code-formatter jupyterlab-lsp nbclassic nbdime jupyterlab-git
```

and then installed again

```
    pip install notebook
    pip install jupyter
```

Magically it worked and the ipywidgets work in the notebook now