error 'Javascript Error: IPython is not defined' while trying to plot in a jupyter notebook
I would like to plot through the code below, I get the error Javascript Error: IPython is not defined.
import backtrader as bt 
import datetime 
import yfinance as yf 
%matplotlib inline


cerebro = bt.Cerebro() 
df = yf.download("BTC-USD", start='2010-01-01') 
df feed = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=df) 
cerebro.adddata(feed) 
cerebro.run() 
cerebro.plot()


i tried installing ipython and other libs and nothing works

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922480/javascript-error-ipython-is-not-defined-in-jupyterlab
