# Matplotlib and plt.connect

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

Good Morning

I have done a bar graph, and I want than a line change of position in the graph bar with a mouse event. Im a novice and I couldn't get it to work, I put the code underneath.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])


df['mean']=df.mean(axis=1)
df['std']=df.std(axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
years = df.index.values.tolist()
averages = df['mean'].values.tolist()
stds =df['std'].values.tolist()
x_pos = np.arange(len(years))
min_value = int(df.values.min())
max_value =int(df.values.max())
yaxis = np.arange(min_value,max_value, 100)
plt.bar(x_pos,averages, color='red')
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Average values per year')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
line = ax.axhline(y=10000,color='black')
traza=[]

def onclick(event):
    if not event.inaxes:
            return
    traza.append('onclick '+event.ydata())
    line.set_data([0,1], event.ydata())

plt.connect('button_press_event', onclick)


plt.show()
```

I can't even get the onclick procedure done. Could you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things are going wrong:

- `event.ydata` is not a function, so you can't call it as `event.ydata()`. Just use it directly.
- When some graphical information changes, the image on the screen isn't updated immediately (as there can be many changes and redrawing continuously could be very slow). After all changes are done, calling `fig.canvas.draw()` will update the screen.
- `'onclick ' + event.ydata` doesn't work. 'onclick ' is a string and `ydata` is a number. To concatenate a string and a number, first convert the number to a string: `'onclick ' + str(event.ydata)`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):
    if not event.inaxes:
        return
    line.set_data([0, 1], event.ydata)
    fig.canvas.draw()

np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000, 200000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(43000, 100000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(43500, 140000, 3650),
                   np.random.normal(48000, 70000, 3650)],
                  index=[1992, 1993, 1994, 1995])

df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['std'] = df.std(axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
years = df.index.values.tolist()
averages = df['mean'].values.tolist()
stds = df['std'].values.tolist()
x_pos = np.arange(len(years))
min_value = int(df.values.min())
max_value = int(df.values.max())
yaxis = np.arange(min_value, max_value, 100)
plt.bar(x_pos, averages, color='red')
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Average values per year')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
line = ax.axhline(y=10000, color='black', linestyle=':')

plt.connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've made the changes you suggested. But I think that for some reason the onclick procedure is never executed. In fact, if it did, I would have seen some of the errors you pointed out.

Comment: This can depend on your environment. If you're running inside a jupyter notebook, you may need `%matplotlib notebook` (not `%matplotlib inline`, which shows the plots without interactivity, see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923313/canvas-mpl-connect-in-jupyter-notebook)). Or you could run inside an interactive environment such as PyCharm.

Comment: Thank you, I found out which was the problem with your last comment.