# How to add a hovering annotation on a bar plot with mplcursors

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, mplcursors

How can I modify this plot to show me the value of each bar upon hovering mouse?

```
sns.barplot(x = "date", y = "no_of_dogs", data = dogs_adopted_per_day, palette="husl")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could employ [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range('20210101', periods=10),
                   "no_of_dogs": np.random.randint(10, 30, 10)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
sns.barplot(x="date", y="no_of_dogs", data=df, palette="husl", ax=ax)

x_dates = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates)

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
@cursor.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    x, y, width, height = sel.artist[sel.target.index].get_bbox().bounds
    sel.annotation.set(text=f"{x_dates[round(x)]}\n{height:.0f}",
                       position=(0, 20), anncoords="offset points")
    sel.annotation.xy = (x + width / 2, y + height)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I tried your code on Jupyter notebook but for some reason, it doesn't work. I don't get any errors too.

Comment: You'll need `%matplotlib notebook` instead of  `%matplotlib inline` to have interactivity. See e.g. [canvas.mpl_connect in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923313/canvas-mpl-connect-in-jupyter-notebook) or [Javascript Error: IPython is not defined in JupyterLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922480/javascript-error-ipython-is-not-defined-in-jupyterlab/56416229#56416229)

Comment: `%matplotlib qt` works in `Jupyter Lab` for interactive plots